# Helm chart and post install job hook during helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a job st as `post-install` in my helm charts which is looks like

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-hook-postinstall
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"

spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: post-install
          image: {{ .Values.image.initContainer.curl }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - >
              PAYLOAD='{"password":"password"}';
              curl -X PUT "http://server:{{ .Values.app.Server.service.port }}/users/userA" -H "Authorization: Basic {{ .Values.app.livenessProbe.Server.authorization }}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw $PAYLOAD &&
              curl -X PUT "http://server:{{ .Values.app.Server.service.port }}/users/userB" -H "Authorization: Basic {{ .Values.app.livenessProbe.Server.authorization }}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw $PAYLOAD
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0

  backoffLimit: 20
  completions: 1
```

which I expect will be executed only during helm install but is getting executed during helm upgrade as well.

Other problem is that it will error out on `Error: failed post-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded` when I have bumped it to 20

Any thoughts on both problems? Can I do some kind of a loop to check if the connection to the server endpoint is present then execute curls to prevent at least second problem? Will below work?

```
...
          command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - >
              for i in $(seq 1 300); do nc -zvw1 server {{ .Values.app.Server.service.port }} && exit 0 || sleep 3;
              done;
              PAYLOAD='{"password":"password"}';'
....
```

or to execute that job after specific pod deployment?